# Running Ansible setup module without an ansible.cfg

Tags: ansible, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I want to run the ansible setup module, by declaring a specific host.

I am using Windows 10 machine , with windows subsystem for linux where ansible is installed.

I can run the setup module when using localhost, ie:

```
ansible localhost -m setup
```

I can run it when using the ansible.cfg file I use from one virtual environment, against a virtual machine ie:

```
ansible TestVm -m setup
```

In another virtual environment i have installed ansible without setting up an ansible.cfg file, and my hosts.yml file is in the windows (not the WSL filesystem).

No matter which directory i switch, I cannot run the setup module using for instance:

```
ansible -i inventory -m setup
```

.

Is there a way to run setup without a configuration file and if yes what part of the call am i missing?

Comment: what is the error you are getting? when you specify -i you probably need to direct it to the correct hosts file. in this case if the hosts.yml is in windows, the filepath will be something like `/mnt/<drive letter>/path`

Comment: I have mounted C drive and I am running it inside the directory containing the host.yml . The error message I get is "ERROR! Missing target hosts". It does not seem to recognise my hosts but I cannot find how to point to the host I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
ansible all -i inventory -m setup
```

Where the inventory is a directory with at least the **hosts.yml** file.

And this an example of **hosts.yml**

```
all:
  hosts:
    192.168.2.9:
    192.168.2.3:
    192.168.2.4:
```

Also before any of these you must have added pywinrm:

```
pip install pywinrm
```